# Serde how to access a field of a struct cast to `impl Serialize`?

Tags: rust, traits, serde

I'm trying to figure out how to access a a field of a struct cast to "impl Serialize"?

Consider the following code:

```
mod Testing {
    #[derive(Serialize, Clone)]
    pub struct One {
        pub valueOne: String,
    }

    #[derive(Serialize, Clone)]
    pub struct Two {
        pub valueOne: String,
        pub valueTwo: String,
    }
}

fn go() -> Result<()> {
    let s = Testing::One {
        valueOne: "Please work",
    };
    self.how(s);
    Ok(())
}

fn how(
    s: impl Serialize,
) -> Result<()> {
    // How to access "valueOne" of "s"?
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: You can't. But this looks like a XY problem.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the field `valueOne` in `how()`, even though both `One` and `Two` have the field. All that is known about `s` in `how()` is that it implements `Serialize`, which is not enough to guarantee it even has the field `valueOne`. `s` could be of type `One`, `Two`, or any other random type that also happens to implement `Serialize` and doesn't include the field `valueOne`.

The proper way to do this is to introduce another trait that provides a getter for `valueOne`. Then you can rely on the trait to provide you that value.

```rust
trait ValueOne {
    fn value_one(&self) -> &str;
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct One {
    pub value_one: String,
}

impl ValueOne for One {
    fn value_one(&self) -> &str {
        &self.value_one
    }
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct Two {
    pub value_one: String,
    pub value_two: String,
}

impl ValueOne for Two {
    fn value_one(&self) -> &str {
        &self.value_one
    }
}

fn go() {
    let s = One {
        value_one: "Please work".to_owned(),
    };
    how(s);
}

fn how(s: impl Serialize + ValueOne) {
    dbg!(s.value_one());
}
```